# Present View Controller right after Dismissing View Controller with no animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, presentviewcontroller

I have a `UIImagePickerController` presented on screen. When I choose the photo I need to dismiss the `PickerController` then immediately present another `PhotoEditController`. Here is my code

```
picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
    self.presentViewController(editPhotoVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
})
```

There is a 0.1s flash between dismissing old VC and presenting new VC so the presentingViewController (self) is shown. How do I avoid that in an elegant solution not hacking it through? Thanks

Comment: Since you're not animating anything, why not just present the viewcontroller without dismissing the previous one? `If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack.`

Comment: How? Apple doesn't allow that

Comment: Sorry, what I'm saying is present your new viewcontroller on the viewcontroller that is already presented (picker).  Then, when you want to dismiss them all, dismiss from the original viewcontroller that presented the first one.

Comment: is picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated right? shouldn't it be just dismissViewControllerAnimated ?

Comment: @LLooggaann I see what you meant. That is actually what I implemented. I have a delegate callback from the editPhotoVC implemented on self to dismiss both view controllers together. You should write an answer and I will mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of implementation is to dismiss first view controller (VC) with animation and present second VC with animation.

However, depending on your view hierarchy, you could also have your second VC loaded first and then present first VC on top of it. With this simply dismissing first VC without animation should show underneath second VC without delay.

Third approach, as LLooggaann suggested, don't dismiss first VC and simply present second VC. Once done, dismiss the entire view controller hierarchy in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate `PhotoEditController`'s instance, then do something like this:

```
instance.willMoveToParentViewController(controllerThatPresentsPicker)
controllerThatPresentsPicker.addChildViewController(instance)
controllerThatPresentsPicker.view.insertSubview(instance.view, belowSubview: picker.view)
instance.didMoveToParentViewController(controllerThatPresentsPicker)
```

It looks a bit like a hack though

Answer (score 0):

That is most probably because dismiss is sent to the VC that presented the picker and it dismisses the picker modal vc and executes the completion handler after attempting to present the parent VC which is itself.
one solution would be creating your own transition class, you can basically copy paste the code from [here](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/custom-uiviewcontroller-transition-ios-swift/) to do that